Initial Rest Condition in Linear Systems
Given the differential equation $\sum_{k=0}^{N} a_k \frac{d^k y}{dt^k} = \sum_{k=0}^{M} b_k \frac{d^k x}{dt^k}$, we can separate the solution to two different responses of the system:

ZSR - the zero state response, i.e. the response of the system to an input and zero initial conditions.
ZIR - the zero input response, i.e. the response of the system to no input and initial conditions.

The general solution is $y=y_{zir}+y_{zsr}$.
The professor said that for a system to be linear, the differential system describing it has to be in initial rest, i.e. the auxiliary conditions over the output are zero:
$y(t_0)=y'(t_0)=...=y^{(k)}(t_0)=0   (1)$.
But if the initial conditions are zero, $y_{zir}$, as a solution to a homogenous linear equation will be zero when the initial conditions are zero.
In previous courses, we had systems with non-zero initial conditions for the ZIR solution (and thus the solution to the homogenous equation was not the trivial solution, i.e. $y_{zir}=0$), and the system was considered LTI. So how come we said that those systems we worked with are linear, if we demand the system to be in initial rest, and without $y_{zir}$ being $0$?
Is it possible that the demand the professor required - (1) - is not accurate? I saw in some textbooks and lecture notes that there were no restrictions over the derivatives...
I would appreciate any insight you can provide.

This is a matter of viewpoint. Both views are correct if one clearly defines what constitutes the system and what constitutes the input. If we say that we have an input signal $x(t)$, and we consider the initial conditions as part of the system, then it is correct to say that the system (if described by a linear differential equation with constant coefficients) is LTI only for vanishing initial conditions. The reason is that for linearity we require the output to scale with the input. However, if we scale the input, the part of the output that is caused by the initial conditions doesn't scale accordingly. Hence, the system must be non-linear for non-zero initial conditions. This view is held by Oppenheim and Schafer in their famous text Discrete-Time Signal Processing.
The other view, which can be found in texts by Lathi (e.g., Linear Systems and Signals), sees the initial conditions as another input or cause. For a system described by a linear differential equation with constant coefficients, linearity applies separately to the input signal and to the initial conditions. I.e., scaling the input signal will scale the zero-state response (ZSR) accordingly, and scaling the initial conditions will scale the zero-input response (ZIR). And due to linearity, the output must be the sum of ZSR and ZIR. According to this view, we can define two types of linearity: 1. zero-input linearity, i.e., linearity with respect to the initial conditions, and 2. zero-state linearity, i.e., linearity with respect to the input signal. A system is linear if it is zero-input linear as well as zero-state linear. All systems described by a linear differential equation with constant coefficients are zero-state and zero-input linear.
